# oncontextmenu doesn't prevent the browser's context menu from appearing when i right click

Tags: jquery, html

i have the following short code

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
  <p class="info">
   Books are the world of information. As said the books are the best friends. A wise    
     man always has a library of several books</p>
  <ul id="contextmenu">
 ........
```

**JS:**

```
$('.info').mousedown(function (event) {
    if (event.button == 2) {
        $('#contextmenu').show();
    }
}
```

I want the browser’s context menu not to appear as default along with our context menu when i right click on .info.

```
oncontextmenu="return false"
```

doesn't work

Comment: Can you replicate this issue on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? I was [unable to](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/cet3a/).

Comment: seems fine http://plnkr.co/edit/9B5a67iRPM0eBdpLcC09?p=preview

Comment: I tested it locally on chrome and replicated the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this javascript in your head tag

```
    <script>
        document.oncontextmenu = function(e){
         return false;
        }
    </script>
```

The following also works for me

```
<html oncontextmenu="return false">
```

Comment: that was quick! it worked that way! do you know why the above code didn't work? thank you very much!

Comment: It works when you move your oncontextmenu="return false" to the html tag and not the body tag. Not sure why though.